# OEM non printable characters in Python strings

Tags: python, delphi, encoding, character-encoding, delphi-7

I´m trying to port some Delphi code that sends data to a Universe database. In order to make the text legible by the DB we need to encode it in OEM.

In Delphi is done this way:

```pascal
    procedure TForm1.GenerarTablasNLS;
    var
      i: integer;
    begin
      for i := 0 to 255 do
      begin
        TablaUV_NLS[i] := AnsiChar(i);
        TablaNLS_UV[i] := AnsiChar(i);   
      end;
      // Nulo final
      TablaUV_NLS[256] := #0;
      TablaNLS_UV[256] := #0;

      OemToCharA(@TablaUV_NLS[1], @TablaUV_NLS[1]);
      CharToOemA(@TablaNLS_UV[1], @TablaNLS_UV[1]);
```

And then we translate our text simply like this

```pascal
    function StringToUniverse(const Value: string): AnsiString;
    var
      p: PChar;
      q: PAnsiChar;
    begin
      SetLength(Result, Length(Value));
      if Value = '' then Exit;

      p := Pointer(Value);
      q := Pointer(Result);
      while p^ <> #0 do
      begin
        q^ := TablaNLS_UV[Ord(AnsiChar(p^))];
        Inc(p);
        Inc(q);
      end;
    end;
```

I follow the same logic in Python using a dictionary that stores each character translation

```py
class StringUniverseDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key

TablaString2UV = StringUniverseDict()

def rellenar_tablas_codificacion():
    TablaString2UV['á'] = ' '       # chr(225) = chr(160)
    TablaString2UV['é'] = '‚'       # chr(233) = chr(130)
    TablaString2UV['í'] = '¡'       # chr(237) = chr(161)
    TablaString2UV['ó'] = '¢'       # chr(243) = chr(162)
    TablaString2UV['ú'] = '£'       # chr(250) = chr(163)
    TablaString2UV['ñ'] = '¤'       # chr(241) = chr(164)
    TablaString2UV['ç'] = '‡'       # chr(231) = chr(135)
    TablaString2UV['Á'] = 'µ'       # chr(193) = chr(181)
    TablaString2UV['É'] = chr(144)  # chr(201) = chr(144)     
    TablaString2UV['Í'] = 'Ö'       # chr(205) = chr(214)
    TablaString2UV['Ó'] = 'à'       # chr(211) = chr(224)
    TablaString2UV['Ñ'] = '¥'       # chr(209) = chr(165)
    TablaString2UV['Ç'] = '€'       # chr(199) = chr(128)
    TablaString2UV['ü'] = chr(129)  # chr(252) = chr(129)     

    TablaString2UV[chr(129)] = '_'  # chr(129) = chr(095)     
    TablaString2UV[chr(141)] = '_'  # chr(141) = chr(095)  
    TablaString2UV['•'] = chr(007)  # chr(149) = chr(007)  
    TablaString2UV['Å'] = chr(143)  # chr(197) = chr(143)     
    TablaString2UV['Ø'] = chr(157)  # chr(216) = chr(157)     
    TablaString2UV['ì'] = chr(141)  # chr(236) = chr(141)
```

This works "fine" as long as I translate using printable characters. For example, the string

```
"á é í ó ú ñ ç Á Í Ó Ú Ñ Ç"
```

is translated, in Delphi, to the following bytes:

```
0xa0 0x20 0x82 0x20 0xa1 0x20 0xa2 0x20 0xa3 0x20 0xa4 0x20 0x87 0x20 0xb5 0x20 0xd6 0x20 0xe0 0x20 0xe9 0x20 0xa5 0x20 0x80 0xfe 0x73 0x64 0x73
```

(á translates to ' ', which is chr(160) or 0xA0 in hexa. é is '‚' or chr(130), 0x82 in hexa, í is '¡', char(161) or 0xA1 in hexa and so on)

In Python, when I try to encode this to OEM I do the following:

```py
def convertir_string_a_universe(cadena_python):
    resultado = ''
    for letra in cadena_python:
        resultado += TablaString2UV[letra]
    return resultado
```

And then, to get the bytes

```py
txt_registro = convertir_string_a_universe(txt_orig)
datos = bytes(txt_registro, 'cp1252')
```

With this I get the following bytes:

```
b'\xa0 \x82 \xa1 \xa2 \xa3 \xa4 \x87 \xb5 \xd6 \xe0 \xe9 \xa5 \x80 \x9a'
```

My problem is that this OEM encoding uses non-printable characters, like in 'É' = chr(144) (0x90 in hexa). If I try to call bytes(txt_registro, 'cp1252') with an array where I hava translated 'É' into chr(0x90) I get this error:

```py
caracteres_mal = 'Éü'
txt_registro = convertir_string_a_universe(txt_orig)
datos = bytes(txt_registro, 'cp1252')

  File "C:\Users\Hector\PyCharmProjects\pyuniverse\pyuniverse\UniverseRegister.py", line 138, in reconstruir_registro_universe
    datos = bytes(txt_registro, 'cp1252')
  File "C:\Users\Hector\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x90' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

How can I do this OEM encoding without raising this UnicodeEncodeError?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#OEM_code_page) suggests that perhaps you should be decoding from cp437 or similar?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and remove Delphi tag because your question is not related to Delphi. You don't need someone knowing Delphi: OemToChar and CharToOem are not Delphi functions, they are Windows API functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `cp1252` does not know about `chr(0x90)`. If you try with `utf-8` instead, it will work.

```py
>>> chr(0x90).encode("utf8")
b'\xc2\x90'
```

I don't understand why you are trying to convert to `cp1252` though: you have applied a custom conversion map and then, with `bytes(txt_registro, 'cp1252')`, you are converting your result again to `cp1552`.

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```py
datos = bytes(txt_orig, 'uv')
```

where `uv` is your cutom codec.

So you would have to write an encoder and a decoder for it (which is basically what you have done already). Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register
to register a new codec. The function you will register with it should return a [CodecInfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.CodecInfo) object described upper in the documentation.

```py
import codecs

def buscar_a_uv(codec):
    if codec == "uv":
        return codecs.CodecInfo(
            convertir_string_a_universe, convertir_universe_a_string, name="uv")
    else:
        return None

codecs.register(buscar_a_uv)
datos = bytes(txt_orig, 'uv')
```

#### EDIT

The encoder/decoder functions should return bytes, so you would need to update `convertir_string_a_universe` a bit.